# Rows of 7 with values from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I want to create a code that get's the values from array `["1", "2", "3"]` and then it creates a new row with 7 of this. The array will have near 90 values, so from 1-7 is in the first row, 8-14 in another and so. I created this code but it just freezes the website and crashes the browser, so I would like you to tell me where's the mistake.

```
var newVals = new Array("1", "2", "3"..."81");
var target = ".content table";
var activeTar = target + " .active";
for(var i = 0; i < newVals.length; i++){
    for (var y = 0; y < 7; y++){
        if(y == 0){
            jQuery(target).append('<tr class="active"></tr>');
        }
        var valId = newVals[i];
        var valImg = "http://sub.domain.com/" + valId + "/picture";
        var valCode = '<td class="cell"><a class="toggleAdd" tabindex="0" data-icon="'+valId+'"><img src="'+valImg+'"></a></td>';
        jQuery(activeTar).append(valCode);
        if(y == 6){
            jQuery(activeTar).removeClass("active");
            y = -1;
        }
    }
}
jQuery(".toggleAdd").live("click", function(){
    jQuery("input", jQuery(this).closest('form')).val(jQuery("input", jQuery(this).closest('form')).val() + jQuery(this).attr("data-icon"));
});
```

Comment: y = -1; Doesnt this create a infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have the `"active"` class just for doing DOM selecto to insert into the proper row.

No need. Just save the row in a variable, append to it, and make and save a new row every seven items.

```
var newVals = new Array("1", "2", "3", /*...,*/ "81"),
    target = jQuery(".content table"),
    activeRow;

$.each(newVals, function(i, valId) {
    if(i % 7 === 0)
        activeRow = jQuery('<tr></tr>').appendTo(target);

    activeRow.append('<td class="cell"><a class="toggleAdd" tabindex="0" data-icon="'+valId+'"><img src="http://sub.domain.com/' + valId + '/picture"></a></td>');
});
```

This uses the modulus operator to determine if it is time to make a new row.

with respect to the handler, you can clean it up a bit if you use variables. Also, if you're using jQuery 1.7 or later, you should use `on` instead of `live`.

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".toggleAdd", function(){
    var input = jQuery(this).closest('form').find("input"),
        v = input.val() + jQuery(this).attr("data-icon");

    input.val(v);
});
```

You should replace `document` with a selector that represents the deepest container that holds all the `.toggleAdd` elements.

Comment: Actually, the code you originally posted worked well. ``if(i % 7)`` so I don't know if I need to change something. Also if possible help me to clean the toggleAdd handler if possible. Thanks

Comment: @Luis: It was `if (!(i % 7)) {`, but I decided at the last minute that the comparison to `0` was a little clearer. Either one will work. I also just cleaned up the variables a little. I'll take a look at the handler.

Comment: Thanks! I'll wait for the handler. Is there any way so it checks and if its the ``n`` row, add a colspan in order to round it to a multiple of 7? I mean, if the array has 79 values, the last row has a ``colspan="5"`` so it turns into 84 cells (84/7=12)

Comment: @Luis: If the colspan only goes on the last cell, do it after the loop. Try this: `target.find("td").last().attr("colspan", 7 - ((newVals.length % 7) || 7))`

Comment: @Luis: Glad it worked, though in my comment above, I think it should be `8 - ((newVals...` instead of `7 -`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17030/discussion-between-luis-and-user1689607)

Comment: Just another thing. Do you know how to detect on Facebook when a new chat window is opened?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you only need to remove your following line:

```
y = -1;
```

and change your following for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < newVals.length; i++){
```

for this one:

```
for(var i = 0; i < newVals.length; i = i + 7){
```

and replace your following line:

```
var valId = newVals[i];
```

for this one:

```
var valId = newVals[i + y];
```

Comment: But if I delete that line, the loop will only work with the first 7 values. How can I continue with 8-14, 15-21 and so?

Comment: the second loop will exit and the first loop will begin again, so will work with all values. Also see my updated answer for another fix to your code. Try it.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. It mantains the value (adds 81 cells) but its 7 times repeated, so just 12 different images appear.

Comment: Ok, now I think I understand what you want, see my updated answer again and try it. :-)